# Spell check for macOS Terminal app?

Tags: macos, command-line

Is there a spelling library or command line tool that can be installed to use on macOS command line Terminal app so I can speak check what I type into `bash`?

Answer (score 4):

You have `look` installed on your system. You can also `grep` /usr/share/dict/words. Even, `curl` with the `dict protocol` using the match key could be useful for spelling. Both `emacs` and `vim` have spellcheck features.

Answer (score 3):

A couple spell check tools available for macOS via Homebrew are listed below. See if they meet your needs:

1. [ispell](https://www.cs.hmc.edu/~geoff/ispell.html): International Ispell is an interactive spell-checking program for Unix which supports a large number of European languages.

   To install via Homebrew run:

   `brew install ispell`
2. [GNU Aspell](http://aspell.net): GNU Aspell is a Free and Open Source spell checker designed to eventually replace Ispell. It can either be used as a library or as an independent spell checker

   To install via Homebrew run:

   `brew install aspell`

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/hunspell/hunspell

`brew install hunspell`

Then go by the link in their README to download the dictionaries in `.oxt` format, rename to `.zip` and unpack. Pass the path to them using `-d` parameter and joined with `,`.

Optionally save the resulting output as `my.txt`, remove the really misspelled words from both the file and the file you check the spelling in, and run again with `-p my.txt` added.